# R Different Prediction Result for Formula Containing "%>%"

Tags: r, lm, magrittr

In R, when I use "predict" to get a confidence interval for a certain x (x=42) under the model: y = (centered x) + (centered x)^2. I found two possible ways:

```
model1 = lm(y ~ scale(x, center=T, scale=F) + I( (scale(x, center=T, scale=F))^2 ), data=data)
model2 = lm(y ~ (x %>% scale(center=T, scale=F)) + I( (x %>% scale(center=T, scale=F))^2 ), data=data)
```

The summary results for the two models are the same. But when I ran:

```
predict(model1, data.frame(x=42), interval="confidence", level=0.95)
predict(model2, data.frame(x=42), interval="confidence", level=0.95)
```

The results are different. I am wondering why. Does R treat the above two formulas differently because of the usage of "%>%"?

The dataset is a practice dataset from Kutner's textbook [SENIC.txt](http://www.cnachtsheim-text.csom.umn.edu/Kutner/Appendix%20C%20Data%20Sets/APPENC01.txt), y is the 11th column, x is the 12th column.

Comment: You should include sample data in your question, using `dput`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with `scale` and not `%>%`. `scale` returns a matrix which seems to affect the outcome.

One solution is to write `vector` --> `vector` equivalent of scale and use it:

```r
library("magrittr") # for `%>%`
set.seed(1)
dataset = data.frame(x = rnorm(30))
dataset[["y"]] = 1 + (3 * dataset[["x"]]) + rnorm(30, mean = 0, sd = 0.1)

scale_vector = function(x, ...){
    stopifnot(inherits(x, "numeric"))
    scale(x, ...)[, 1]
}

lm(y ~ scale_vector(x, center=T, scale=F) + I( (scale_vector(x, center=T, scale=F))^2 ), data=dataset)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ scale_vector(x, center = T, scale = F) + I((scale_vector(x, 
#>     center = T, scale = F))^2), data = dataset)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                                   (Intercept)  
#>                                       1.27423  
#>        scale_vector(x, center = T, scale = F)  
#>                                       2.99296  
#> I((scale_vector(x, center = T, scale = F))^2)  
#>                                      -0.01645

lm(y ~ (x %>% scale_vector(center=T, scale=F)) + I( (x %>% scale_vector(center=T, scale=F))^2 ), data=dataset)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ (x %>% scale_vector(center = T, scale = F)) + 
#>     I((x %>% scale_vector(center = T, scale = F))^2), data = dataset)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                                      (Intercept)  
#>                                          1.27423  
#>        x %>% scale_vector(center = T, scale = F)  
#>                                          2.99296  
#> I((x %>% scale_vector(center = T, scale = F))^2)  
#>                                         -0.01645
```

---

Besides, if you do not mind using tidyverse, this might be cleaner:

```r
library("magrittr") # for `%>%`
set.seed(1)
dataset = tibble::tibble(x = rnorm(30),
                         y = 1 + (3 * x) + rnorm(30, mean = 0, sd = 0.1)
                         ) 

dataset %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(x_scaled = scale(x, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)[, 1]) %>% 
    lm(y ~ x_scaled + I(x_scaled^2), data = .)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ x_scaled + I(x_scaled^2), data = .)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>   (Intercept)       x_scaled  I(x_scaled^2)  
#>       1.27423        2.99296       -0.01645
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is not with the `summary` results, but with the `predict(..., "confidence")` results. I ran the model with `%>% scale_vector` but the predict confidence intervals are different in the same way as I mentioned in the question. (As I said, the summary results are always the same even if without vectorizing `scale`.)